# Modify wp-query and sort by post meta key

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I am trying to modify a query, but can not figure out how to sort the results by  post meta and then randomize the results.

The key I am sorting by has 6 possible values: gold, silver, bronze, copper, basic and free.

I need to randomly sort by the first five key\values or exclude free. Then random sort the last possible value free.

I have tried this, but the code breaks and does not randimoze each clause:

```
$query->set( 'meta_query' => array(
    'paid_clause' => array(
        'key' => '_membership_level',
        'value' => 'free',
        'meta_compare' => '!=',
    ),
    'free_clause' => array(
        'key' => '_membership_level',
        'value' => 'free',
        'meta_compare' => '=',
    ), 
) );

$query->set( 'orderby' => array( 
    'paid_clause' => 'ASC',
    'free_clause' => 'ASC',
) );
```

Comment: Could you add an example of your desired input/output. I'm not 100% sure I'm reading your question (which is quite interesting) correctly. Like if you had 10 post in the db with the terms you've described, what would you want them to look like on the front-end?

Comment: I have the front end working as I need it to; however, I need to sort the output into two groups. First show all the posts where the value in the post meta key "_membership_level" is not "free" and then show all the posts where the meta key value is "free". I also need to each group to have a random order.

Comment: It's going to be fairly simple to do with two loops. It could be done within a pre_get_posts function, but it'd take a little while to scratch build & test.

Comment: I am good with how to use the action.